# How can I use Rails/Devise without a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am creating a Rails app that does not use a database. Instead, the model is managed using a Ruby API that wraps a legacy system.

I have a Ruby call that will allow me to validate a username/password combination. Is it possible to use Devise (or some other off-the-shelf authentication solution) in this case?

My hope is that I can override a few methods in Devise and still get many of the benefits.

Peter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it is possible.

You may override the default authentication and use a remote service with Devise and Warden.

This blog post gives you details how:

http://4trabes.com/2012/10/31/remote-authentication-with-devise/

Let us know how it goes...

Good luck

Comment: The page you identify describes the kind of solution that I want to implement. However, it is quite vague on a number of details. Where does the User PORO live for example. Are there three User classes or just one? And where do the Devise::Models and Devise::Strategies modules live?

Comment: Gah! I needed to add 'Devise.add_module :remote_authenticatable, :controller => :sessions,  :route => { :session => :routes }' to my devise.rb file. I've never met a language with so much voodoo as Ruby. Can anyone explain what this line does?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to use Devise in your project to wrap old legacy authentication system. 
You might need something like to define legacy_username and legacy_password methods, create a migration to adopt to Devise gem, and I believe you will find your way out.
Maybe this link can help you out: http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2012/05/13/how-to-migrate-passwords-from-legacy-systems-to-devise/

And also, maybe this - how to create custom encryptor in Devise - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-custom-encryptor

I hope it will help.

Comment: The trouble is that I don't have a database. So ActiveRecord::Base isn't in my vocabulary. Also, I don't deal with encryption.