# How to run devise by ActiveResource ( RESTFUL API ) instead of ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

By default, using ActiveRecord in rails , we save data into database.
But in my case , instead of save into database , i need to create a request to a RESTFUl webservice , so i need to use ActiveResource instead of ActiveRecord in Model.
But when i replace ActiveRecord by ActiveResource in Model , i get this error :

***Uncaught exception: undefined method `devise' for User:Class***

My model code :

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
self.site = "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

How can i use Devise with ActiveResource ?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14865456/791026

Comment: Or can i override all CRUD method in ActiveRecord ( by ActiveResource )???